# executing script before 60 seconds

Tags: php

I am creating simple script to test that I can echo inside my while loop before it gets 60 seconds,but the problem is it will not echo inside my loop.I don't know if it is really executed inside my while loop. Then my browser will crashed.

```
$timelimit = 60; //seconds
set_time_limit($timelimit);
$start_time = time(); //set startup time;



while(((time() - $start_time) < $timelimit) || !$timelimit){
    echo "executing..<br/>";
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: If your browser crashes while loading the page, I would assume it is being overloaded by probably millions of lines of `executing` being received from the server. A single `echo` statement requires **very** few time. You should add `usleep(100000);` (sleep 100000 microseconds/100 milliseconds) in your loop to limit execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very tight loop. It will run very fast and will create a very large output, which will eventually kill the browser (it will have hundreds of thousands of lines). You may add some delay to your loop:

```
while(((time() - $start_time) < $timelimit) || !$timelimit){
    sleep(1); // pause for 1 second
    echo "executing..<br/>";
}
```

In this case the output will be only 60 lines, and the browser should render it after a minute of waiting.

Answer (score 1):

CPU execution is very first (approximately `10^-9s` per execution). Your looping time is `60 seconds`. So consider how many (may be `300915626` executions) executions will occur. During this time if you want to print something your browser will be killed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting to see the output as the script generates it, then you'll want to add a `flush();` after your echo. However, if I recall correctly, php will still wait to send the output until it has a certain number of bytes (1024 maybe?)